# WSO2 EI, custom API not sending response

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have created my two sequences like this:

```
<sequence name="test_seq_in">
    <in>
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"hello": "world"}</format>
            <args/>
        </payloadFactory>
    </in>
    <out>
        <send/>
    </out>
</sequence>
```

Second sequence is like this:

```
<sequence name="test_seq_out">
    <out>
        <send/>
    </out>
</sequence>
```

Then I have created API like this:

```
<api context="/test" name="test">
    <resource inSequence="test_seq_in" methods="GET" outSequence="test_seq_out"/>
</api>
```

My WSO2 EI created invocation url `http://192.168.56.1:8280/test`. When I make GET request to this address it returns to me nothing.

I just want to show `{"hello": "world"}` json when on `http://192.168.56.1:8280/test` address made GEt request.

Why this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 'respond' instead of 'send' in the insequence as that is what you want to do.

```
<sequence name="test_seq_in">
        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"hello": "world"}</format>
            <args/>
        </payloadFactory>
        <respond/>
</sequence>
```